# Getting 404 "Not Found" after messing with Apache's configuration

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, linode

Earlier I was trying to set up HTTPS on mediawiki and followed a guide that said to remove "Listen 80" on the ports.conf Apache file. As soon as I did that the website went down and not its displaying a 404 error not found. I did add the Listen 80 line again but to no avail.

I'm running a linode VPS (Debian 10) with LAMP, Wordpress installed and now mediawiki.

I am new to the Linux environment so I'm not entirely sure what could be wrong, but I suspect there's a misconfiguration in the Apache files. When I initially installed Wordpress, I moved the entire site to www/html and deleted the Wordpress folder so it would load on my domain's main page. Everything was working perfectly fine until I changed that "Listen 80" line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Things I tried:

- Restarting apache
- Checking the several configuration files and making sure the directories are correct

Comment: Are you getting an Apache-404 or a Wiki Not Found? Because if is the first one, make sure you're listening to the 80/443 port in your vhost which has the document root to the right directory. If is the second one, you're probably just missing the hidden `.htaccess` file when you moved files.

Comment: Uploading the configuration file would help with diagnosing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up "Virtual Host" correctly. When you put "Listen 80" into you configuration file, You need to set up more things there, like path to the folder (directory) where you have stored all your web stuff.

This is how my apache configuration file looks like:

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-custom.conf

```
listen 8081

<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /web/CustomDirectory

    ErrorLog /weblogs/8081e.log
    CustomLog /weblogs8081c.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps :)